# Breaking change in class XmlWriterBackedStream with KB2901983

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I have an application targeting .NET Framework 4.0 and yesterday our customer did some kind of update and our app stopped working. After some digging in the .NET Framework source code I found the reason in the XmlWriterBackedStream class. The code on my machine reads as follows:

```
// C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
// System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: .NET 4.0

// System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamBodyWriter.XmlWriterBackedStream
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    if (this.writer.WriteState == WriteState.Start)
    {
        this.writer.WriteStartElement("Binary", string.Empty);
        this.writer.WriteBase64(buffer, offset, count);
        return;
    }
    if (this.writer.WriteState == WriteState.Content)
    {
        this.writer.WriteBase64(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```

whilest the .NET 4.0 Framework code on the customers machine reads like this:

```
// C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
// System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: .NET 4.0

// System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamBodyWriter.XmlWriterBackedStream
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    if (this.writer.WriteState == WriteState.Content || this.isQuirkedTo40Behavior)
    {
        this.writer.WriteBase64(buffer, offset, count);
        return;
    }
    if (this.writer.WriteState == WriteState.Start)
    {
        this.writer.WriteStartElement("Binary", string.Empty);
        this.writer.WriteBase64(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```

Note the `this.isQuirkedTo40Behavior` on the cutomers machine. This has forced me to compile the app against the .NET Framework 4.5 in order to get it working again.

Is this a bug in the .NET Framework? How can I get my app working again without targeting the 4.5 framework?

This is my class that caused the proplems:

```
class MyMessageWriter : StreamBodyWriter
{
   private readonly Action<System.IO.Stream> writerAction;

   public MyMessageWriter(Action<System.IO.Stream> writer) : base(false)
   {
      this.writerAction = writer;
   }

   protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(System.IO.Stream stream)
   {
      this.writerAction(stream);
   }
}
```

Comment: Probably an update that exists on their machine and not yours. You should check the version numbers of both DLLs, then search for the customer's version number to find the update and details about what's going on.  Adding a "quirks mode" in and update isn't a "bug".  (assuming that the //ver number in your code samples isn't from the strong name of the assembly but something in code?)

Comment: Here's the KB for this issue http://smallbusiness.support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2925382

Comment: @Will: I would agree about the "quirks mode" if it wouldn't brake the app. Only the revision number is higher on the customer machine... Thanks for the link - I missed that :-(

Comment: Yeah.  So they have an update you don't have on your machine.  The question is how to fix this?  Perhaps you can snatch the update, then recompile against 4.0?  You might have to fix runtime errors, but having them on your machine is better than debugging remotely or via a dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be realy a breaking change which comes with the install of KB2901983 (thanks Microsoft!). However I've found a way to work around this issue, so you can still target your app to .NET Framework 4.0 (a bit ugly - but it works):

```
class MyMessageWriter : StreamBodyWriter
{
   private readonly Action<System.IO.Stream> writerAction;

   public MyMessageWriter(Action<System.IO.Stream> writer) : base(false)
   {
      this.writerAction = writer;
   }

   protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(System.IO.Stream stream)
   {
      this.writerAction(stream);
   }

   protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   {
      writer.WriteStartElement("Binary", string.Empty);
      writer.WriteBase64(new byte[0], 0, 0); // force WriteState.Content

      base.OnWriteBodyContents(writer);
   }
}
```

**Update**

This solution doesn't seem to work if you have KB2901983 not installed.

**Update 2**

I had to add `writer.WriteBase64(new byte[0], 0, 0)` in order to force the State of XmlDictionaryWriter to `WriteState.Content` now it should work before and after the installation of KB2901983

**Update 3**

An alternative solution would be to wrap the XmlDictionaryWriter into your own Stream derived class